# Is pg_dump tool exporting dead tuples

Tags: postgresql

I am using the pg_dump tool (version 10.18), for table export, are dead tuples if there is any also exported and are present in the dump file?

Comment: No they are not. Easy enough to test, dump a table in plain text and see what is in the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Dead tuples” are not visible.  Since `pg_dump` gets its data by running a `SELECT` statement against the table to be dumped, it won't see those deat tuples either, so it won't dump them.

Comment: Ok thanks Laurenz